# Displaying all clickedData Item in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I would like to ask about making list by doing clicked event in AngularJS, so here is the problem, if you click plunker below you will see a list of items(string) with a value there, when I want to click a value then the blank list there will contained the value that I clicked...

My goal is to make a list with the item that I clicked and I would like to remove it through a button there, but I would like to focus on how to display all item that I clicked first.

So in the practice, when you clicked "Gila" first and then it will appear in the blank list, after that when I clicked "yuko", I would like to try how to display after "Gila" and it make a list

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <title>Belajar Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('tesapp', []);
      app.controller('tesCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.DapatkanItem = function(){
          $http.get('sengaja.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.item = data;
          });
        };

        $scope.DapatkanItem();

        $scope.klikIseng = function(item){
          $scope.namaItem = item.name;
        };

        $scope.tampilKlikItem = function(){

        }
      });

        app.filter('regex', function() {
          return function(input, field, regex) {
              var patt = new RegExp(regex);
              var out = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                  if(patt.test(input[i][field]))
                      out.push(input[i]);
              }
            return out;
          };
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="tesapp" ng-controller="tesCtrl">
    <h1>Mencoba Filtering</h1>
    <h2>Mencoba ng-click</h2>
    <div class="col col-4">
      <label class="select">
        <select name="gender" ng-model="alfabet">
          <option value="^" selected disabled>Alphabet</option>
          <option value="^(A|a)">A</option>
          <option value="^(B|b)">B</option>
          <option value="^(C|c)">C</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{namaItem}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-switch="alfabet">
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | regex:'name':alfabet | orderBy: 'preparation' | orderBy: 'name'">
          <input type="button" ng-click="klikIseng(tes)" value="klik gue">
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == ''" >{{tes.name}} kosong</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '1'">{{tes.name}} satu</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '2'">{{tes.name}} dua</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '3'">{{tes.name}} tiga</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | orderBy: 'preparation'">
          <li>{{tes.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/phpaP3oZ3sTbHiuAv44w?p=preview

thank you for your answers and views

Answer (score 0):

you can nameItem to be array, and push the names into it, then display it in your markup using ng-repeat.

this is a simplified answer, you will need to add a function to remove names, and run a check if a name appears before you push it into the array. good luck

here's an updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YKtB8avE0ncgV6JrUIv0?p=preview)

```
$scope.namaItem = [];
$scope.klikIseng = function(item){
   $scope.namaItem.push(item.name);
};
```

html :

```
<li ng-repeat="name in namaItem track by $index">{{name}}</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it solved my problem, as for your concern about function... If I make it into CRUD system, will the item that I remove is also removed from the json?

Comment: it will only be removed from the temporary array container 'namaItem'. acced the answer if it helped you